Usage of the passive with を?

恋愛を抑圧された精神では自覚せず、けれど本能は理解していたから縋りついた…？）

Is を in this sentence being used like に or が?
"A love restrained by the mind"
or "A mind restrained by love"?

This question is similar to: Subject and object of a passive sentence are interchangeable?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


恋愛を抑圧された精神
a mind whose loving/romance (capacity/aspect/ability) has been suppressed
a mind with its loving part repressed

This construction is known as indirect passive. 恋愛が抑圧された精神 also makes sense, but 恋愛を抑圧された精神 emphasizes the negative effect on the mind.

Passive form - The exact difference between を and が
How to interpret indirect passives?
「を」 object marker in this 受身形{うけみけい} sentence

